# Find sequences that does not match to a target sequence

Tags: search, bioinformatics, dna-sequence, blast, ncbi

An interesting question by [Rnaer](http://www.biostars.org/u/1599/) from [Biostar](http://www.biostars.org/p/87315/#87336):

> I want to find unique dna/protein sequences of a given length (30nt, for example)
>   that does not match to any region of the C.elegans genome. Is there
>   any tool to do that?

Comment: Well, it is a really interesting question :-) Unfortunately, I can't predict a long survival for it. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NCBI provides an easy way to search DNA/Amino acid sequence databases that DO NOT match to a target organisms genome, yet match to other databases and sources.

Just use the `exclude field` in [NCBI's BLASTn](http://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PROGRAM=blastn&PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&LINK_LOC=blasthome)

[image]

Hope this was useful.